# ms access no display my Arabic language

Tags: netbeans, character-encoding, ms-access-2010

problem when I enter data from the netbeans to ms access, the access displaying it as طظظط$ظ ،etc o am writing it in Arabic language .. Any help please?

Comment: Are you using the JDBC-ODBC Bridge? If so, then you'll probably never get it to work correctly with Arabic characters.

Comment: So what should I use?

Comment: [Manipulating an Access database from Java without ODBC](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21955256/2144390)

Comment: I gonna try it , thank you so much

Comment: That code doesn't work with me , I am using netbeans 6.7.1, ucanaccess 3.0.3.1 ,commons-lang 2.6  , commons.logging 1.1.1, hsqldb.jar , jackcess 2.1.3